# How do I make for loop with if else code more concise

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    var decisionCol = values[i][29];
    if (decisionCol == ""){
      orderDate = values[i][0];
      orderNo = values[i][1];
      orderRevenue = values[i][16];
    } else {
      orderDate = values[i][11];
      orderNo = values[i][6];
      orderRevenue = values[i][30];
    }
    output.appendRow([output.getLastRow(), orderDate, orderNo, orderRevenue, prodPrice]);
  }
```

I have google apps code above but it looks ugly.
How do I make it shorter and concise?

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [for-of loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)? Changing `for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++)` to `for (const value of values)` will certainly make your code cleaner and eliminate the 2-dimensional array references.

```js
for (const value of values){
    var decisionCol = value[29];
    if (decisionCol == ""){
      orderDate = value[0];
      orderNo = value[1];
      orderRevenue = value[16];
    } else {
      orderDate = value[11];
      orderNo = value[6];
      orderRevenue = value[30];
    }
    output.appendRow([output.getLastRow(), orderDate, orderNo, orderRevenue, prodPrice]);
  }
```

Beyond this change, I don't know if there are other changes I would recommend. Your code snippet is already quite short, so it is hard to recommend further refinements. Your code is very easy to understand and follow what is going on. That's a good thing! Attempts to get creative to be more concise might make your code shorter but could also make it harder to follow.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- When `appendRow()` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

  - I would like to propose to put the values using `setValues()`.
- In your situation, `getLastRow()` can be used at outside of the loop.

When your script is modified using above points, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var lastRow = output.getLastRow();
var res = values.map(r => [lastRow++, r[29] == "" ? [r[0], r[1], r[16]] : [r[11], r[6], r[30]], prodPrice].flat());
output.getRange(output.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that the variables of `values`, `output` and `prodPrice` are correctly declared. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Hi Tanaike. Please try to refrain from adding "Please think of this as just one of many possible answers" to your answers. Readers already know this (it is pretty obvious). You need not worry that readers will religiously use your material just on the basis that you have provided it. It is always the reader's responsibility to check the suitability of material they find on the internet.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for your advice. And I deeply apologize. I understood your advice.

Comment: You are welcome. As ever, apologies not necessary 